# Ionic Creator-Listitem icon Override with item-body

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view, ionic-popup

I am creating a layout on https://creator.ionic.io/.
I am facing problem while I am including `listitem` with icon with class `item-body`. I am giving `item-body` class because my content is goes outside of the boundary and if i write `item-body` class in list-item then text is overwritten on icon.

Did anybody find a  solution for this problem or has anyone faced the same problem ?

[image: Please check Image by Clicking here..]

Comment: The best way to ignore this error is separate both in different grid layout.